# wordpress permalinks 404

Tags: apache, wordpress

i've read wordpress and the post on here for fixing this and i'm stuck.

i just setup a stock apache2 server with wordpress. my default link for posts works however other options don't.

i've deleted .htaccess and let wordpress regen an not working. by the way i even chmod 666 777 660 nothing works.

The only thing in my .htaccess is two lines begin and end wordpress. i added override above all and still nothing.

I looked in apached2.conf but see no modules for loading overrides.

is this a server issue or wordpress permission or something. if I can narrow it to one side or the other.

also http.conf is empty if that helps.

I got it. had to chown www-data my /var/www

Comment: Might be a RewriteBase issue. Impossible to tell without a single line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you enable mod_rewrite in http.conf?

Earlier SO question: [How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Comment: my http.conf is empty. nothing to enable

Comment: i read article and tried sudo a2enmod rewrite, and it worked thank you so very much.....:)